# Sql commands for showing all foreign keys/indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to debug my database in phpmyadmin/mysql. Which is the best command to see all of the foreign keys and indexes in the database?

Is there also a way to look at possible index and foreign key errors?

Comment: When you ask about `possible index and foreign key errors` what are you refering to?

Comment: @Yaroslav The problem is that if I try and drop and index or a forign key I am getting errors that an index can't be deleted due to a contraint or error #1025 for when I try drop a foriegn key. I want to run a command to see where all the foriegn keys and indexes are situated so it will be easier for me to debug

Comment: Understood. Then please edit your question and add the error you are receiving and the action that triggers it (when trying to drop index/foreign key). Doing this you will get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will show you all the foreign keys:

```
SELECT concat(table_name, '.', column_name) as 'foreign key',
       concat(referenced_table_name, '.', referenced_column_name) as 'references'
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage
 WHERE referenced_table_name is not null;
```

This other one shows you all the indexes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS;
```